# Maintain list of points while using SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently using GMapping to build a map. While building the map, I would like to be able to save points of interest that I can command the robot to navigate to at any time. While maintaining a list of points is easy, I have noticed that sometimes GMapping shifts the map and reshapes it while it is mapping. This usually happens once a loop is closed. If this happens, the list of saved points is no longer accurate.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before, or are there any SLAM algorithms out there that deal with this? If not, can you suggest what part of GMapping would need to be changed to provide the ability to keep the points in the correct relative location?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213727/maintain-list-of-points-while-using-slam/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2015-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt that this is possible with GMapping. In general, graph-based approaches to the SLAM-Problem are able to solve the described issue. Selected points of interest can be added to the internal graph and thus get shifted together with the surrounding map when a loop-closure happens.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2015-07-17**:
I was thinking with GMapping the individual particles could be edited to hold onto a list of points, but that would result in a lot of memory overhead. I will look around for graph based slam algorithms, thanks for the tip!